# Сортировка обьектов при считывании из файла - Java

Tags: java

Всем привет,у меня есть файл в который я записываю обьекты, а потом их считываю. И сейчас я хочу их считывать с сортировкой, но что бы записаны были как я записал, а уже считывать с сортировкой. И так, у меня каждый обьект имеет имя, фимилию и пять оценок с предметов, так вот я хочу считьвать их на основе среднией из оценок по возростанию. Вот мой код что я имею на данный момент:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String imie = "", nazwisko = "";
        double al = 0.0, po = 0.0, ptw = 0.0, ja = 0.0, wf = 0.0;
        System.out.print("Ile studentow chcesz dodac: ");
        int counter = scanner.nextInt();
        String[] daneImieNazwisko = new String[counter * 2];
        int imieCounter = 0, nazwiskoCounter = 1;
        double[] daneOceny = new double[counter * 5];
        int ocena01Counter = 0, ocena02Counter = 1, ocena03Counter = 2, ocena04Counter = 3, ocena05Counter = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            System.out.print("Podaj imie i nazwisko studenta" + (i + 1) + "\n");
            scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("imie: ");
            imie = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("nazwisko: ");
            nazwisko = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Podaj ocene z przedmiotow\n");
            System.out.print("algebra liniowa: ");
            al = scanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("programowanie obiektowe: ");
            po = scanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("podstawy technologii www: ");
            ptw = scanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("jezyk angielski: ");
            ja = scanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("wychowanie fizyczne: ");
            wf = scanner.nextDouble();

            daneImieNazwisko[imieCounter] = imie;
            imieCounter = imieCounter + 2;
            daneImieNazwisko[nazwiskoCounter] = nazwisko;
            nazwiskoCounter = nazwiskoCounter + 2;

            daneOceny[ocena01Counter] = al;
            ocena01Counter = ocena01Counter + 5;
            daneOceny[ocena02Counter] = po;
            ocena02Counter = ocena02Counter + 5;
            daneOceny[ocena03Counter] = ptw;
            ocena03Counter = ocena03Counter + 5;
            daneOceny[ocena04Counter] = ja;
            ocena04Counter = ocena04Counter + 5;
            daneOceny[ocena05Counter] = wf;
            ocena05Counter = ocena05Counter + 5;

        }

//        for (int i = 0; i < daneImieNazwisko.length; i++) {
//            System.out.print(daneImieNazwisko[i] + " ");
//        }
//        System.out.print("\n");
//        for (int i = 0; i < daneOceny.length; i++) {
//            System.out.print(daneOceny[i] + " ");
//        }

        System.out.print("\n");

        Student student01 = new Student(daneImieNazwisko[0], daneImieNazwisko[1], daneOceny[0], daneOceny[1], daneOceny[2], daneOceny[3], daneOceny[4]);
        System.out.print("\nDane studenta1: \n");
        System.out.print(student01.showImieNazwisko() + "\n");
        System.out.print(student01.showOceny());

        System.out.print("\n");

        Student student02 = new Student(daneImieNazwisko[2], daneImieNazwisko[3], daneOceny[5], daneOceny[6], daneOceny[7], daneOceny[8], daneOceny[9]);
        System.out.print("\nDane studenta2: \n");
        System.out.print(student02.showImieNazwisko() + "\n");
        System.out.print(student02.showOceny());

        System.out.print("\n");

        Student student03 = new Student(daneImieNazwisko[4], daneImieNazwisko[5], daneOceny[10], daneOceny[11], daneOceny[12], daneOceny[13], daneOceny[14]);
        System.out.print("\nDane studenta3: \n");
        System.out.print(student03.showImieNazwisko() + "\n");
        System.out.print(student03.showOceny());

        System.out.print("\n");

        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("wynikiStudenci.ser"));
            students.add(student01);
            students.add(student02);
            students.add(student03);
            for (Student student : students) {
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(student);
            }
            objectOutputStream.flush();
            objectOutputStream.close();
            System.out.print("Dane studentow zostaly zapisane do pliku \"wynikiStudenci.ser\"");
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.print("Blad: " + exc);
        }

        System.out.print("\n");
        students.removeAll(students);
        try {
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("wynikiStudenci.ser"));
            while (true) {
                try {
                    students.add((Student) objectInputStream.readObject());
//                    Student obj = (Student) objectInputStream.readObject();

                } catch (EOFException exc) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            objectInputStream.close();
            for (Student student : students) {
                System.out.print("\n" + student.showImieNazwisko() + "\n" + student.showOceny());
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.print("Blad: " + exc);
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.company;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Student implements Serializable {
    private String imie;
    private String nazwisko;
    private Indeks indeks;
    private String test;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return test;
    }
    public Student(String imie, String nazwisko, double ocena01, double ocena02, double ocena03, double ocena04, double ocena05) {
        this.imie = imie;
        this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
        this.indeks = new Indeks(ocena01, ocena02, ocena03, ocena04, ocena05);
    }

    public String getImie() {
        return imie;
    }

    public String getNazwisko() {
        return nazwisko;
    }

    public String showImieNazwisko() {
        String s = "Imie: " + getImie() + "\n" + "Nazwisko: " + getNazwisko();
        return s;
    }

    public String showOceny() {
        String p01 = indeks.getPrzedmiot01() + " / " + indeks.getOcena01();
        String p02 = indeks.getPrzedmiot02() + " / " + indeks.getOcena02();
        String p03 = indeks.getPrzedmiot03() + " / " + indeks.getOcena03();
        String p04 = indeks.getPrzedmiot04() + " / " + indeks.getOcena04();
        String p05 = indeks.getPrzedmiot05() + " / " + indeks.getOcena05();
        return p01 + "\n" + p02 + "\n" + p03 + "\n" + p04 + "\n" + p05;
    }
}
```

```
package com.company;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Indeks implements Serializable {
    private String przedmiot01 = "Algebra liniowa";
    private String przedmiot02 = "Programowanie obiektowe";
    private String przedmiot03 = "Podstawy technologii WWW";
    private String przedmiot04 = "Jezyk angielski";
    private String przedmiot05 = "Wychowanie fizyczne";

    private double ocena01 = 4.0;
    private double ocena02 = 4.0;
    private double ocena03 = 4.0;
    private double ocena04 = 4.0;
    private double ocena05 = 4.0;

    public Indeks(double ocena01, double ocena02, double ocena03, double ocena04, double ocena05) {
        this.ocena01 = ocena01;
        this.ocena02 = ocena02;
        this.ocena03 = ocena03;
        this.ocena04 = ocena04;
        this.ocena05 = ocena05;
    }

    public String getPrzedmiot01() {
        return przedmiot01;
    }

    public String getPrzedmiot02() {
        return przedmiot02;
    }

    public String getPrzedmiot03() {
        return przedmiot03;
    }

    public String getPrzedmiot04() {
        return przedmiot04;
    }

    public String getPrzedmiot05() {
        return przedmiot05;
    }

    public double getOcena01() {
        return ocena01;
    }

    public double getOcena02() {
        return ocena02;
    }

    public double getOcena03() {
        return ocena03;
    }

    public double getOcena04() {
        return ocena04;
    }

    public double getOcena05() {
        return ocena05;
    }
}
```

Comment: то есть сортировать по среднему арифметическому оценок?

Comment: @да, именно так, по возростанию

Comment: Ваш вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к "считыванию из файла". Уберите весь ненужный код и спросите, как отсортировать список объектов.

Comment: @Igor проблема в том что я не хочу записывать сортированные обьекты, а только сортировать их при считывании

Comment: Перечитайте мой предыдущий комментарий. Не нужно никакое "сортировать их при считывании". Прочитайте все объекты (судя по коду, Вы это умеете) и отсортируйте список независимо от того, откуда взялось его содержимое..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам верно указали в комментариях, что для данной задачи нужно отсортировать список перед выводом, а откуда вы читаете объекты - не важно.

Как вариант:

Имплементируйте [интерфейc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) `Comparable<T>` в классе `Student` так:

```
public class Student implements Serializable, Comparable<Student> {...}
```

Переопределите метод `compareTo(T o)` например так (это пример только **для демонстрации** логики `compareTo(T o)` для вашей задачи):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    int result = 0;
    double avgThis = (indeks.getOcena01()
            + indeks.getOcena02()
            + indeks.getOcena03()
            + indeks.getOcena04()
            + indeks.getOcena05()) / 5;
    double avgThat = (o.indeks.getOcena01()
            + o.indeks.getOcena02()
            + o.indeks.getOcena03()
            + o.indeks.getOcena04()
            + o.indeks.getOcena05()) / 5;
    if (avgThis > avgThat) {
        result = 1;
    } else if (avgThis < avgThat) {
        result = -1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Отсортируйте список `students` перед выводом на консоль (или перед записью в файл) так:

```
Collections.sort(students);
```

Данный пример простой и показывает, как достигается возможность сортировать объекты, но в вашей задаче правильнее использовать [компараторы](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).